# Derivative of complex inverse function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a complex invertible function. I know that if $f^{-1}$ is continuous in $z_0$ and the derivative $f'(f^{-1}(z_0))$ exist and is non-zero, then $(f^{-1})'(z_0)$ exists and
$$
(f^{-1})'(z_0)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(z_0))}
$$
My question is why we need to know that $f^{-1}$ is continuous in $z_0$? I know how we use it in the proof, but I can not find an example of an invertible function $f$, such that $f'(f^{-1}(z_0))$ exist and is non-zero, but $(f^{-1})'(z_0)$ does not exists.

Comment: A counterexample would need to be non-analytic at $f^{-1}(z_0)$, due to the inverse function theorem.

Comment: It looks like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705379/diferentiable-function-with-non-differentiable-inverse) example  can be readily extended to the complex case by setting $f(z) = z$ for $z \in \mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R$. This will give you a counterexample

Comment: thanks @user2628206